# Take HTML form data to python

Tags: python, html

I want to take HTML form data and handle the submited data(string for example) with my python application.

The html file with the form will be stored locally and values will be entered from a browser.
I then want to take the submited values to my python application.

How do I do with the form action and link it to my application? Please point me in the right direction.

BR,

Comment: Which WSGI framework is your python web application using?

Comment: There is way too little information here to let us help you. Do you already use a python web framework, for example?

Comment: Sorry, bear with me. I'm fresh in the area. I've not setup a web server yet and also have no WSGI for my application. I guess my question should be; what frameworks should I look into? Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to execute your application from the web application you would like to create, then you can go for anything from bare cgi scripts (in say ... Perl) through PHP script and even Django (Python based web framework). It all depend on what you like to do :)

If your intention is to integrate your Python app with the web app, you can try doing it in Django web framework.

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds like you'd just like to open a static html file locally and record and submitted forms.

If this is the case, understand you'll still need some sort of web server running locally to receive the POST or GET data.

This could easily be a simple python script in itself, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530787/simple-http-web-server) for ideas.